# Filling a sheet from an array with Excel VBA takes very long

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this Excel VBA code that is taking more than 5 seconds for dumping a 166 row size array in a workbook sheet.
I tried to hide the worksheet but all I get is the "waiting" icon for each single cell.

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add

For row = 0 To UBound(fullReport, 1)
    For col = 0 To UBound(fullReport, 2)
       wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(row + 1, col + 1) = fullReport(row, col)
    Next col
Next row
```

The strange thing is that the first time is always slow and then, sometimes after, it's immediate.

Comment: Do you have formulas that depend on the values you set? Also try setting the array in one go, `wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(fullReport, 1), Ubound(fullReport, 2)).Value = fullReport`.

Comment: You can see a video of it in action: https://goo.gl/re3uQg 29 rows take 6 seconds. Last ones go fast, first ones, slow.

Comment: Woah GSerg!! it works incredibly well. I didn't know that an array could be assigned in one go like that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the beginning of your macro. Your code should run faster.

Comment: I trid but the difference was minimal. The code it really worked was replacing the double For loop with
wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(fullReport, 1), Ubound(fullReport, 2)).Value = fullReport